# Verilog: trying to blink leds in series using a clock divider at multiple frequencies

Tags: verilog, led, flip-flop

I'm trying to use two switches to select the frequency I want to blink the led's at. My verilog code is as follows:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module clk_divider(
    input clk,
    input rst,
     input [1:0] sw,
    output led
    );

reg n;

always@(sw[0],sw[1])
    n = (27 - sw);

    wire [n-1:0] din;
    wire [n-1:0] clkdiv;

    dff dff_inst0 (
         .clk(clk),
         .rst(rst),
         .D(din[0]),
         .Q(clkdiv[0])
    );


    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 1; i < n; i=i+1) 
        begin : dff_gen_label
             dff dff_inst (
                  .clk(clkdiv[i-1]),
                  .rst(rst),
                  .D(din[i]),
                  .Q(clkdiv[i])
             );
             end
    endgenerate;

    assign din = ~clkdiv;

    assign led = clkdiv[n-1];

endmodule
```

When I check for syntax, it says that "n is not constant." How can I avoid this error? To me, it seems that it should work. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: The easiest way would be to create multiple "clocks" tied to a selector.  The selector would then determine which clock powers the led.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to `wire [n-1:0] din;` and `wire [n-1:0] clkdiv;`, you cannot have the width of a bus dependent on the value of an input.

A bus width is defined at synthesis time, it is the number of wires that exist in the physical device. Wires cannot appear or disappear based on the state of a module input or register.

You need to define these wires as having a fixed width, not a dynamic width. Maybe in some cases not all the wires will be used, but you must still define the bus as the maximum width that you will ever need. Similarly in the generate loop, you cannot change the number of flip-flops that are instantiated based on the value of n. You must instantiate as many flip flops as you will ever need, and then enable/disable some as needed.

Also you will hit this separate issue later, but your register `n` is only a single bit, so it cannot store any number other than 0 or 1. Make the register larger if you intend to hold greater values.

Comment: I made adjustments to the code mostly I initialized all the wires that I could ever use to a constant.

On the note of the enable/disable, I added a enable/disable input to my dff, but I am unsure of how to assert a '1' or a '0' to that input in the loop?